# What is the "matrix-norm" of a vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-norms

What does this notation mean?

$$
||\mathbf{x}||_{A}
$$

- $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$
- $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ a square matrix (positive definite, if that happens to be relevant).

Searches for "matrix norm" always refer to norms for matrices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can mean $\sqrt{\mathbf{x}^T A \mathbf{x}}$, you can look into "The Mahalanobis Norm" or "The Energy Norm" for more details/googling.

Edit: as mentioned in a comment below, it more commonly refers to  $\|x\|_A :=\sqrt{\mathbf{x}^T A^{-1} \mathbf{x}}$, which is frequently used in statistics.

Comment: Normally it's the matrix inverse so $\sqrt{x^TA^{-1}x}$.

Comment: From what I’ve seen it can be used both ways, which is a little unfortunate

Comment: It's very rare to define $A$ as a precision matrix instead of a covariance matrix. Unless the context is clear, you should assume that $A$ is a covariance matrix and that you need to use its inverse.

Comment: Good to know. I think I was thinking of it in terms of numerical analysis, where it frequently pops up (and can refers to just $\sqrt{\mathbf{x}^T A \mathbf{x}}$), such as in Conjugate Gradient Descent.